# asp.net c# - A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in my class:

```
    public string StrLog {get; set;}
```

then within the same class, I have the following code:

```
    private string imgData = StrLog;
```

I get the following error message:

```
    A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property
```

It has a problem with:

```
    private string imgData = StrLog;
```

but not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: How does the code know what object belongs to StrLog, you've declared a public property of the class (this property is associated with a class object).

Comment: The field initializers run before the properties initializers, so `StrLog` isn't created yet. (Gross over simplification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you cannot initialise a class level variable by using any other class level value (unless that value is static) - which is what your error is trying to tell you.

Your best option would be to assign the value in your constructor:

```
private string imgData = null;

public MyClass()
{
   imgData = "some value";
}
```

In your case there is no point assigning it the value of `StrLog` because `StrLog` won't have a value to begin with. So you may as well just assign it `null`, or an actual value form somewhere else (like my example)

Comment: Thanks.  How do I set the value of imgData with  StrLog as I had it as -  public string StrLog {get; set;}. Basically, how do I set imgData to the value of the Property that I will be passing in.

Comment: Why? It doesn't make sense. Just read from `StrLog` whenever you need it rather than reading from `imgData`

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use a non-static memeber to intialize a member variable.

You need to intialize it first by setting it up in your constructor.

eg:

`imgData = null;`

I would strongly encourage you to assign *something* (something could be null) in the constructor. It's just *good form.* In the example below, you will see why it is important. What if a get is executed first and the value isn't set? It should at least contain a null value.

Having said that, if you want the value of imgData to be populated with the value of your public-facing property, you need to do the following:

```
public string StrLog
{
   get { return imgData; }
   set { imgData = value; }
}
```

This will pass the value of StrLog into imgData, with no work required on your part.

Answer (score -1):

Make imgData your property , same way as Strlog. and then assign . it will work.